# AJAX call with Express

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am trying to append HTML dynamically with Express framework in a static HTML file that my server serves. I've found about the cheerio module that does exactly what I want, but I was wondering if there is a much cheaper way for the system instead of loading the whole HTML and appending a string.

I searched about AJAX and how to communicate with the client but I didn't manage to make it work. The code I am using with cheerio is:

```
exports.modify = function(req, res){

  var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../public/index.html', 'utf8'); 
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  var scriptNode = '<p>Source code modified</p>';
  $('body').append(scriptNode);

  fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/../public/index.html', $.html(), function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('It\'s modified!');
    });

  res.send($.html());

};
```

How can I do it in more 'proper' way (maybe with AJAX call)? Any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do.

If you want to handle JSON as a data type then you can setup another specific route or you can filter the request type within the current route handler :

   exports.index = function(req, res) {
     var data = someData.fetch();
     switch(req.format) {
       case 'json':
         res.json(data);
         break;
       default:
         res.render('template', {
         data:data
       });
      }
    };

Comment: I just want the modify route to send the scriptNode as the above code shows to the client index.html with AJAX, then fetch it and write it to the file, without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: You have to have 3 routes. 1. The HTML page with forms and client side javascript 2. A route the would return scriptPage, called from client side javascript 3. A route to modify the serverSide version based on client side request.

The way you describe your problem shows that you don't really understand how routes and client / server side should be handled. Reading express documentation would be useful.

Comment: Can you show me a small example to be more clear to me? Thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: Honestly no... I don't have time to make a tutorial + there are tons of good one available.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to handle JSON as a data type then you can setup another specific route or you can filter the request type within the current route handler :

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  var data = someData.fetch();
  switch(req.format) {
    case 'json':
      res.json(data);
      break;
    default:
      res.render('template', {
      data:data
    });
  }
};
```